# Anopheles arabiensis lifespan and sporogony duration

Tags: entomology, mathematical-models, epidemiology, death, malaria

What is the longest observed lifespan of a mosquito, especially of the species *Anopheles arabiensis*? How long does it take for *Plasmodium* parasites to develop and move into the salivary glands of these mosquitoes?

I need this information to calibrate my model on malaria transmission.

Answer (score 2):

**What is the longest observed lifespan of a mosquito, especially of the species *Anopheles arabiensis*?**

Mean lifespan calculations for *Anopheles arabiensis* range from 14 days ([Karoki, 2013](http://ir.jkuat.ac.ke/bitstream/handle/123456789/1337/Karoki,%20SM-%20Msc%20Epidemeiology%20and%20Lab.pdf))* to 21 days ([Yamada *et al*. 2014](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001706X14003829))**

*This Masters thesis tests efficacy of different drugs against *An. arabiensis*, 14 days is the mean control lifespan.
**These *An. arabiensis* are of a specific strain but no indication is given that the life span is different than normal *An. arabiensis*.

The CDC [*Anopheles* mosquito page](http://www.cdc.gov/malaria/about/biology/mosquitoes/index.html) is another good source for information on *Anopheles* life spans:

> The adult females can live up to a month (or more in captivity) but most probably do not live more than 1-2 weeks in nature.

**How long does it take for *Plasmodium* parasites to develop and move into the salivary glands of these mosquitoes?**

US [National Institutes of Health](http://www.niaid.nih.gov/topics/malaria/pages/lifecycle.aspx):

> Growth and division of each oocyst produces thousands of active haploid forms called sporozoites. After 8-15 days, the oocyst bursts, releasing sporozoites into the body cavity of the mosquito, from which they travel to and invade the mosquito salivary glands.

[United States Air Force](http://www.phsource.us/PH/PARA/Chapter_9.htm) (USAF):

> The length of the developmental stage in the mosquito not only depends on the *Plasmodium* species but also the mosquito host and the ambient temperature.  This may range from eight days in *Plasmodium vivax* to as long as 30 days in *Plasmodium malariae*.

Wikipedia ([*Plasmodium falciparum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasmodium_falciparum_biology#Mosquito_stage)) :

> Over the period of a 1–3 weeks, the oocyst grows to a size of tens to hundreds of micrometres... The sporozoites then migrate to the salivary glands and complete their differentiation. Once mature, the sporozoites can proceed to infect a human host during a subsequent mosquito bite.

US [Center for Disease Control](http://www.cdc.gov/malaria/about/biology/):

> After 10-18 days, the parasites are found (as "sporozoites") in the mosquito's salivary glands. When the *Anopheles* mosquito takes a blood meal on another human, the sporozoites are injected with the mosquito's saliva and start another human infection when they parasitize the liver cells.

**Overall**, it depends who you ask, but especially on the species of *Plasmodium* you're working with. I'd look for specific papers on the development cycle you're modeling and run with it.